# PHP if statement inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to write the below array if a value is set. How can I do this inside of an array? I know I could use a ternary operator but i'm not sure how.

```
            array(
                'name' => 'extraFields',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'name' => 'portal',
                ),
             if($Value === 1){
   //Need to write the below when value is true
                    array(
                        'name' => 'portal',
                        'value'=> '',
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'id' => '1',
                            'value'=> 'testportal',
                        ),
                    ),

                           }
            ),
```

Comment: First of all you should assign your Array instantiations to a variable for further access and maybe submission of the data: $dataArray = array(...).

Comment: `if($Value = 1)` < is that supposed to represent pseudo?

Comment: If it isn't pseudo, then it will always be true/equal to 1. You're assigning instead of comparing.

Comment: $Value is a variable, it's either equal to 1 or 0 depending on the users choice in a previous form. Let me adjust it, should be $Value === 1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 3 variants to do this:

```
// Variant 1
// Anonymous function, variables from the parent scope
$Value = 1;
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'extraFields',
    'attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'portal',
    ),
    'ifArray' => function() use ($Value) {
        if ($Value == 1) 
            return array(
                'name' => 'portal',
                'value'=> '',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'value'=> 'testportal',
                ),
            );
    }
);

print_r($arr['ifArray']());
```

```
// Variant 2
// Anonymous function, variable assignment
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'extraFields',
    'attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'portal',
    ),
    'ifArray' => function($Value) {
        if ($Value == 1) 
            return array(
                'name' => 'portal',
                'value'=> '',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'value'=> 'testportal',
                ),
            );
    }
);

$Value = 1;
print_r($arr['ifArray']($Value));
```

```
// Variant 3
// Ternar operator
$Value = 1;
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'extraFields',
    'attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'portal',
    ),
    'ifArray' => $Value != 1 ? null : array(
        'name' => 'portal',
        'value'=> '',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'value'=> 'testportal',
        )
    )
);

print_r($arr['ifArray']);
```

However, the variant that El_Vanja suggested, might be more clear than those three.

Comment: The difference between this approach and mine is that these solutions will always add and index `'ifArray'` with a value.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot intersect a definition of an array with a conditional statement. What you need to do instead is to define your array first and then do an if statement which will add to the array. It's not entirely clear at what level of your array you want to add the conditional content, so I'll show it on a simplified example:

```
$value = 1;
$myArray = array(
    'name' => 'Joe',
    'kids' => array(
        'name' => 'Mary',
    ),
);
if ($value === 1) {
    $myArray['kids']['hobbies'] = 'kite flying';
}
```

After this, the variable `$myArray` will have the following content:

```
array(
    'name' => 'Joe',
    'kids' => array(
        'name' => 'Mary',
        'hobbies' => 'kite flying',
    ),
)
```

Where exactly you need to put your conditional data depends on the full structure of your array, but the idea is you access the parts you want through indices.

Edit: in case you can just add the needed subarray at the end of your array, you can utilize [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push).

Comment: What if I want to add another array inside that array? I'm generating an XML from it so I need to be able to put an array inside an array based off a a given criteria.

Comment: In that case you simply assign an array under that index: `$myArray['kids']['hobbies'] = array('kite flying', ...);`.